# Nodejs app not able to connect Mongodb Altas,AWS EC2 instance when testing android app from device but works on emulator

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, mongodb-atlas

I create an android mobile app using java, backend using nodejs mongodb.
I have connected mongodb to mongodb atlas and AWS ec2 instance public ip on android url.

When running the application on emulator and postman, the application works fine (on mongodb atlas and EC2 instance) but when I try to test (internal test goggle play) the application on android device, shows the error:

> Errorunexpected end of stream on Connection{}, proxy=DIRECT hostAdress=/ cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}

I am not able to establish connection when do test using the mobile device.

My url

```
package com.xxx.xxx.url;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class url {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://11.111.111.111:3001/";
    public static String imagePath = BASE_URL;
    public static String token = "Bearer ";
    public static String userId = "";
    public static String status = "Status";

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit;

    }
}
```